# Can clickhouse WITH FILL be used fill a specified amount of missing values?

Tags: sql, clickhouse

I have a dataset of (wallet) ids, dates, and eod_balance. The issue is that the dataset only includes entires for the days that the balance changed. Using Clickhouse I need to write a query that returns a balance for each wallet at each day, including changes but only on the day they were made.

Here is an example dataset:

| id | date | eod_balance |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123x | 2020-03-02 | 2000 |
| x567 | 2020-03-02 | 5000 |
| a123 | 2020-03-02 | 1234 |
| b456 | 2020-03-02 | 32 |
| c233 | 2020-03-03 | 23 |
| 129x | 2020-03-04 | 1000 |

Here is what I would like returned:

| id | date | eod_balance |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123x | 2020-03-02 | 2000 |
| x567 | 2020-03-02 | 5000 |
| a123 | 2020-03-02 | 1234 |
| b456 | 2020-03-02 | 32 |
| 123x | 2020-03-03 | 2000 |
| x567 | 2020-03-03 | 5000 |
| a123 | 2020-03-03 | 1234 |
| b456 | 2020-03-03 | 32 |
| c233 | 2020-03-03 | 23 |
| 123x | 2020-03-04 | 2000 |
| x567 | 2020-03-04 | 5000 |
| a123 | 2020-03-04 | 1234 |
| b456 | 2020-03-04 | 32 |
| c233 | 2020-03-04 | 23 |
| 129x | 2020-03-04 | 1000 |

As you can see, there should be a tuple for each wallet at each day.

My rough thought process is that `WITH FILL` should be used to add rows corresponding to the number of unique IDs that precede a given row but I am new to Clickhouse so I'm not sure if that is possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like that:

```
with date_range as (
select toDate(arrayJoin(arrayMap(x -> toDateTime(x), range(toUInt32(toStartOfDay(toDate('2020-03-02'))), toUInt32(toStartOfDay(toDate(now()))), 86400)))) as Date
), base as (
select t.id as id, st.date as date, sum(t.eod_balance) as eod_balance
from temp t
inner join (select st.id, min(st.date) as date
            from temp st
            group by st.id) st on st.id = t.id and st.date = t.`date` 
group by t.id, st.date
)
select dr.Date, b.id, b.eod_balance 
from date_range dr
cross join base b
where dr.Date >= b.`date` 
order by dr.Date, b.id
```

The data I used in my test (temp) table:

```
|id  |date      |eod_balance|
|----|----------|-----------|
|123x|2020-03-02|2 000      |
|x567|2020-03-02|5 000      |
|a123|2020-03-02|1 234      |
|b456|2020-03-02|32         |
|c233|2020-03-03|23         |
|129x|2020-03-04|1 000      |
|123x|2020-03-05|1 000      |
|x567|2020-03-02|1 000      |
```

The last two rows simulate a change in the 123x wallet at a different date and a change in the x567 at the same wallet's creation date, as I understand, you don't want to see changes if they are not from the creation's wallet date but you want to have the changes within the creation date.

This is my result (I stopped at the 2020-03-07 for my test but the query will return data until today):

```
|Date      |id  |eod_balance|
|----------|----|-----------|
|2020-03-02|123x|2 000      |
|2020-03-02|a123|1 234      |
|2020-03-02|b456|32         |
|2020-03-02|x567|6 000      |
|2020-03-03|123x|2 000      |
|2020-03-03|a123|1 234      |
|2020-03-03|b456|32         |
|2020-03-03|c233|23         |
|2020-03-03|x567|6 000      |
|2020-03-04|123x|2 000      |
|2020-03-04|129x|1 000      |
|2020-03-04|a123|1 234      |
|2020-03-04|b456|32         |
|2020-03-04|c233|23         |
|2020-03-04|x567|6 000      |
|2020-03-05|123x|2 000      |
|2020-03-05|129x|1 000      |
|2020-03-05|a123|1 234      |
|2020-03-05|b456|32         |
|2020-03-05|c233|23         |
|2020-03-05|x567|6 000      |
|2020-03-06|123x|2 000      |
|2020-03-06|129x|1 000      |
|2020-03-06|a123|1 234      |
|2020-03-06|b456|32         |
|2020-03-06|c233|23         |
|2020-03-06|x567|6 000      |
|2020-03-07|123x|2 000      |
|2020-03-07|129x|1 000      |
|2020-03-07|a123|1 234      |
|2020-03-07|b456|32         |
|2020-03-07|c233|23         |
|2020-03-07|x567|6 000      |
```